# Несколько шаблонов для 404 страницы Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, error404

Стоит задача для админки и для клиентской части сделать разные страницы ошибок 404. Я хотел это сделать в App\Exceptions\Handler в методе render(), но здесь пользователь еще не загружен \Auth:user() отдает null;

Поэтому проверить это админ и находится ли он на страницах админки нет возможности. Соответственно на фронте тоже не ок получается. Когда вылетает 404 ошибка помимо всего прочего, на юзер панеле отображается, что он не залогинен, что само по себе плохо, т.к. реально пользователь залогинен.

Как в 404 шаблоне удерживать информацию о пользователе? Как правильно будет отдать для разных пользователей разные 404 страницы?

Есть вариант добавить `app/Http/Kernel.php` в свойство `$middleware` строчку

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Таким образом юзер прогружется в `App\Exceptions\Handler` но такой метод убивает сесию в роутах, если мы попробуем передать из контроллера что-то типа

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => 'Ошибка при сохранеии, что-то пошло не так...'])->withInput();
```

То ничего не увидим в глобальной переменной `$errors`, которая доступна во вьюхах, ничего нет.

Comment: Ну у админки есть префикс в url, наверняка. Можно по нему.

Comment: а middleware на что?

Comment: @Евгений Николаев можете поподробнее описать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю правильным решением будет использовать метод fallback(), в файле роутов в самом низу нужно добавить

```
Route::fallback('NotFoundController@index');
```

И в контроллере можно вызвать нужную вьюшку.

Второе решение добавить в `app/Http/Kernel.php` в свойство `$middleware` следующий код

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Но при этом в свойстве `$middlewareGroups['web']` нужно удалить эти самые 3 строчки кода. Такое решение наверное не самое лучшее так как мы будем запускать во всем приложении, то что не везде должно запускаться. Возможно это повлияет на безопасность приложения.